# Wordpress: jQuery.load some php file

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to load some dynamic data with jQuery after document load.
For example, let it be tag cloud:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#sidebar-tags').load('<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/tag_cloud.php');
});
</script>
```

And in tag_cloud.php something like this:

```
<? wp_tag_cloud(''); ?>
```

And ofcoz it doesn't work, "Internal server error".
How can i make this idea work?

**Solved:**

Followed Plamen Nikolov's link, came up with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
         data : ({action: "get_tag_cloud"}),
         success: function(response) {
            alert(response);}
         })
});
</script>
```

and in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_tag_cloud', 'get_tag_cloud');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_tag_cloud', 'get_tag_cloud');
function get_tag_cloud() {
    echo json_encode(wp_tag_cloud('echo=0'));
    die();
}
```

It almost works: if I check it with Firebug, I can see the response, but the alert doesn't pop up.

Comment: try executing the URL directly in browser. The error is in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a XHR request (Ajax) you must stick to the recommended way, using the proper hooks:

See the examples here: [WordPress Ajax hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)

Answer (score 0):

The code functionality in tag_cloud.php is wrong and it responses internal server error. In order to develop wordpress widget you can have a look at following tutorial

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/creating-a-wordpress-network-widget

Also be sure that, you are calling correct url in jquery load function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sidebar").html($.get('<?php echo bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/tag_cloud.php');
```

You have to either escape single-quotes around `template_url` or use double-quotes. Read your server logs for further debugging.